# Calculate possible intersection point of two lines

Tags: coordinate-systems

[image]

I'd like to know the $I$ coordinates $[x, y]$. $I$ is the possible intersection point of line $|AB|$ with $|XY|$ and $|X'Y'|$. Values that are known:

- Angle $AIX$ and $AIX'$
- Coordinates of points $A$, $B$, $X$, $Y$, $X'$, $Y'$

I have no idea how to calculate intersection point of two lines that do not directly intersect.

Thanks a lot in advance.

PS: Gray lines are imaginary

Comment: $I$ is entirely defined by the points $X,Y,A,B$, the positions of $X',Y'$ have no influence on the solution. To obtain it, try to formulate the equations of the corresponding grey lines, that continue $|AB|$ and $|XY|$ and solve for the intersection point $I$.

Comment: $X'$, and $Y'$ is just different position of $X$ and $Y$...I'm now trying to calculate equation (sth. like $y = ax + b$) for each line and then calculate intersection (using equality between those two equations).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the coordinates $(x,y)$ of your four points $A,B,X,Y$, the parametrized equations for the two continuation lines are

$$\vec{r}_1(t)
=\begin{bmatrix}x_A \\ y_A \end{bmatrix}
+t\cdot\begin{bmatrix}x_B-x_A \\ y_B-y_A \end{bmatrix},$$

$$\vec{r}_2(s)
=\begin{bmatrix}x_X \\ y_X \end{bmatrix}
+s\cdot\begin{bmatrix}x_Y-x_X \\ y_Y-y_X \end{bmatrix}.$$

Set $\vec{r}_1(t)=\vec{r}_2(s)$ and solve for the parameters $(s_0,t_0)$. Putting the parameter value into the above equations tells you the intersection point, e.g. 
$$\vec{r}_I=\vec{r}_1(t_0),\qquad \text{or}\qquad  \vec{r}_I=\vec{r}_2(s_0).$$

**EDIT** Assume for example the positions
$$A:(0,1),\quad B:(0,2),\quad X:(1,1),\quad Y:(2,2)$$
(which is a bit similar to your picture)

Then the line-equations are

$$\vec{r}_1 (t) =\begin{bmatrix}0 \\ t \end{bmatrix},\qquad 
\vec{r}_2(s)=\begin{bmatrix}1+s \\ 1+s \end{bmatrix}.$$

Setting them equal gives the set of equations

$$0=1+s,\\t=1+s,$$

with the solution $(s_0,t_0)=(-1,0)$. Computing your intersection point as explained above, you obtain
$$\vec{r}_I = \vec{r}_1(0)=\begin{bmatrix}0 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix}.$$

Comment: Could you please provide numerical example? What is $t$ ans $s$? I made equations using this tutorial http://www.mathsisfun.com/algebra/line-equation-2points.html.

Comment: @PeterO. Your tutorial uses an *implicit description* where the line is given as $y=f(x)$, I use an *explicit parametrisation* $x=x_1(t),y=y_1(t)$ where $t$ is a real parameter. For each value of $t$ you get a point on the line, for example in the above example $t=0$ gives $A$, $t=1$ gives $B$. To understand the form $\vec{r}(t)=\vec{A}+t(\vec{B}-\vec{A})$, draw a picture. $\vec{A}$ brings you to the point $A$, and the difference vector $(\vec{B}-\vec{A})$ points from $A$ to $B$. When changing $t$ it is resized, or for $t<0$ goes backwards, so all points are visited by changing the parameter.

Comment: I have to admit that I'm not a friend with math :( I think that we'll both achieve the same goal but you are using university approach and I'm using highschool one :)

Comment: @PeterO. You can do it the way you like, there is no problem with that :) If you get stuck, just keep asking!

Comment: I'd like to see any step-by-step example of your approach with numerical values e.g. a link to school materials...If it's possible.

Comment: @PeterO. I added added an example for you.